# How to attach an existing mysql volume to a new container?

Tags: docker

I pull mysql image and I want to run a container with that image, but instead of creating a new volume I'd like to use my existing mysql-db volume (mysql tables inside that volume)

what is the easiest way to do that?

---

I run this command but after 5 seconds the container's no longer running

```
docker run --name db-server -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=aaaa -v /mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

Comment: How did you start the first container?  Is it still running?  (Docker or not, you can’t run two MySQL instances on the same data store.) What actual error messages do you get?

Comment: I created a container with tables, deleted the container, and now I want to create a new mysql container with that volume, thankU

Comment: I can't run this container, only see it when I run the following command:  docker container ls -a

Answer (score 0):

docker run --name ganesh-mysql -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypasswd -d mysql:latest